# Filter the list based on a list inside

Tags: c#, .net, list, linq, lambda

I have this models

```
public class ModelA {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<ModelB> ModelBClass { get; set; }
}

public class ModelB {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ModelAId { get; set; }
    public ModelA modelA { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

And I'm using the below LINQ to filter that will show all ModelA with a ModelB IsActive status = true

```
_dbContext.ModelA.Include(c=>c.ModelBClass.Where(d=>d.IsActive == true)).ToListAsync();
```

But I'm getting an error: "Lambda expression used inside Include is not valid

Tried other things to filter but doesn't help. I want to show all ModelA with all the IsActive: true for all ModelB class.

Comment: Tried all the suggestion there, but it didn't work

Comment: which version of ef are you using, Where inside include is specific to dotnet 6 I think.

Comment: Yup we're using .NET 6.0

Comment: Another suggestion would be to use a different param name for Where Lambda `Where(b=>b.IsActive == true)`

Comment: Tried that one too but didn't work. I edited my question to include that param for Lambda.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250954/discussion-between-code-name-jack-and-code-boy).

Comment: You have a ModelA as field in ModelB, and ModelB as a Navigation in ModelA. Ef doesn't handle Two-way navigations well. Please look at your generated migration and Foriegn keys. Include it here if possible.

Comment: *show all ModelA with all the IsActive: true for all ModelB class*. Should either use: `.Where(a => a.ModelBClass.All(b => b.IsActive))` or `.Where(a => !a.ModelBClass.Any(b => !b.IsActive))`

Answer (score 0):

I do  not believe you want a filtered include, which does not filter the outer collection. Instead you want a `.Where( ... .Any(...))` condition that essentially does the equivalent of a SQL `WHERE EXISTS(...)`.

Try something like:

```
_dbContext.ModelA
    .Include(a = a.ModelBClass)
    .Where(a => a.ModelBClass.Any(b => b.IsActive))
    .ToListAsync();
```

The include might not be needed. You can try both with and without.

Comment: Tried your both suggestion but it didn't work. It still getting the record of ModelBClass that has IsActive = false

Comment: I think you may be trying to do two different things here. The Where condition I suggested should limit the returned collection of ModelA objecta to those associated with at least one ModelB having IsActive = true. Did that part work? The other part you seem to be asking is to also filter the included ModelB objects. My understanding is that .Include() only controls eager loading of the objects. Even those not initially loaded may be accessible via the linked collection. When you later process the ModelA objects and access the ModelB collection, you may still need to apply the filter.

Comment: ... However, I am not familiar with the filtered include implementation, so perhaps someone else can fill in the gaps.

Answer (score 0):

You can show all ModelA with all the IsActive: true for all ModelB class using `Where` to filter a sequence of values and `All()` to determine whether element of a sequence satisfy a condition:

```
_dbContext.ModelA.Where(c => c.ModelBClass.All(d => d.IsActive)).ToListAsync();
```